# How to programatically determine Android device setup timestamp

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to programmatically determine the timestamp of when an Android device was setup, just like how it can be found in [Find my device](https://www.google.com/android/find) under "First registered".

[image]

I've tried looking at the creation dates of the files in the device but most of them seem to update daily and are not good indications of the creation date.